# C# TCPListener Issue

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I have the following code to listen to TCP/IP connections on localhost on my computer. When I run the app (WPF application), I receive the following error messages.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Updated Code:

```
try
{
    string sConnectionString = "Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Integrated Security=false;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx";

    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    Console.WriteLine("Starting TCP listener...");

    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 13002);

    listener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server is listening on " + listener.LocalEndpoint);

        Socket client = listener.AcceptSocket();

        var childSocketThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[100];
            int size = client.Receive(data);

            string incomingMess = " ";

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                incomingMess = incomingMess + Convert.ToChar(data[i]);

            Console.WriteLine("---> Message recorded in DB");
            Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine);

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);

            string regMess = "insert into Messages(incomingMessage) values(@incomingMessage_param)";
            SqlCommand regMessCommand = new SqlCommand(regMess, con);

            con.Open();
            regMessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@incomingMessage_param", incomingMess);
            regMessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            client.Close();
        });
        childSocketThread.Start();
    }

    listener.Stop();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.StackTrace);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: What are the error messages?--you are only showing us the StackTrace.

Comment: Seeing the stacktrace coming from `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)` maybe the it failed to bind to port 13000 because something else is listening on it?

Comment: Yes - what is the error? Nevertheless, don't put that code into the constructor, use Window.Loaded or a timer delay.

Comment: Make sure your fire wall allows you to bind. When networking I recommend originally turning your firewall off, and turning back on at the end

Comment: @JeffRSon--oh yeah, wow.  I missed that.  The window will never display if the listener works--the code is designed to loop forever, and since it's in the window constructor, that window won't ever be able to display, unless you get an exception in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect your program has previously been bound to this port and the port hasn't been released when you've terminated the process from its loop - if you change the port number to 13001/13002/13003/something else random, do you find you still get the exception?

Comment: One step backwards: We would like to create an application which will receive messages from external devices 24/7. In this case, the IP address will be the IP of the server but I am wondering how the port number should be selected? Until now, I have moved the code to Form_Load (now I use Forms instead of WPF) and changed the port to 13001. However, I still receive the same StackTrace information (if I do not trace it, I do not get any error messages but I see that the whole code is not executed).

Comment: Ok, could you update the main question with your new code please? Additionally, if you could describe the kind of data you're looking to receive from these devices, that would also potentially affect the solution

Comment: The code worked without any problem in a Console Application. I updated the code above.